# JQuery selector for an element without any attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to select an/all element which doesn't have any attribute associated with it.is there any way to select particular element without considering what attributes other paragraphs tags contain?

**For example:**

```
<p class="a" id="para1">This is paragraph 1</p>
<p id="para2" class="a b c d e f" >This is paragraph 2</p>
......
......
<p>This is paragraph 3</p> <!-- select this p without attribute -->
<div>
  <p class="inside-div" id="para5">This is paragraph</p>
</div> <!-- select this div without attribute-->
```

Comment: You can, but why do you need it?

Comment: its just for curiosity.

Comment: `$("p").filter(function() { return this.attributes.length === 0; })`

Comment: SO is so fickle. Accepted answer gets 1 upvote, other answer gets 6 upvotes (entered at the same time) yet is limited to just `p` so fails to solve OPs question for "any", not just "p".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all elements without attributes, use selector `body>*` along with the attributes filter (otherwise you get html/head/title etc)

```
$("body>*").filter(function() { 
    return this.attributes.length === 0; 
})
```

Simple [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bjp1t48y/) with OPs html

Comment: its wonderful allowing me to select all elements with no attributes thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use attributes collection of html element to find out if there is any attribute.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rpavvqgp/)

```
ps = $('p').filter(function(){
   return this.attributes.length == 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is better for code reuse, since it adds/extends jQuery selector.

#### HTML

Example HTML:

```html
<span>Text</span>
<span>Text123</span>
<span id="test">Text123</span>
```

#### jQuery

The noattr selector:

```js
$.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {  
  noattr: function (el) {
    return el.attributes.length == 0;
  }
});
```

Example with the `:noattr` selector.

```js
const noAttributeElements = $("span:noattr");
console.log(noAttributeElements[0]); //<span>Text</span>
console.log(noAttributeElements[1]); //<span>Text123</span>
console.log(noAttributeElements[2]); //undefined
```