# Select element without any data attribute in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list and I want to select first list element "li" without any data attribute

```
<ul>
    <li data-row="down"><a class="scroll" href="#home">home</a></li>
    <li data-space="down"><a class="scroll" href="#home">home</a></li>
    <li data-direction="down"><a class="scroll" href="#about">about</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#team">team</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#service">service</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
    <li data-direction="down"><a class="scroll" href="#blog">blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

I know how to deselect specific data attribute

```
document.querySelector('li:not([data-direction])');
```

but I need something more universal

```
document.querySelector('li:not([data-*])');
```

this doesn't work

Comment: You need more than just a selector, for example filtering. But the sensible, efficient and clean solution would be to add a class to the elements you want to select.

Comment: Why not giving first li tag a unique ID `id="first"` then let selector be 
 `document.querySelector('#first')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [queryselector get elements where attribute starts with 'xxx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623353/queryselector-get-elements-where-attribute-starts-with-xxx)

Comment: I don't think this is possible using `querySelector` alone. Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623353/queryselector-get-elements-where-attribute-starts-with-xxx)?

Comment: @DenysSéguret thank you for your answer. Can you please write down code with filtering solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery selector for an element without any attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254207/jquery-selector-for-an-element-without-any-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

```
const getAllElements = selector => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)
const isDataAttribute = attr => attr.startsWith('data-')
const hasDataAttribute = el =>
  Array.from(el.attributes)
    .every(isDataAttribute) 

getAllElements('li')
  .filter(hasDataAttribute)
```

Comment: Don't use `!!….filter(…).length`. Use `.every` or `.some`.